# Swagger-UI Pattern Breaking the description output

Tags: json, yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a spec json file with patterns
something like this

```
"url": {
                  "description": "URL to be called when the WebHook\r\nevent occurs",
                  "type": "string"
              },
              "connectionString": {
                  "description": "Connection string of the target service bus topic.",
                  "maxLength": 8192,
                  "minLength": 0,
                  "pattern": "^([^=;]+=[^=;]+)(;[^=;]+=[^;]+)*$",
                  "type": "string"
                  
              },
              "description": {
                  "description": "Description is information provided to\r\nhelp the consumer identify this \r\nwebhook description",
                  "maxLength": 8192,
                  "minLength": 0,
                  "pattern": "^[^<|^>]+$",
                  "type": "string"
              }
```

but the output is not coming out as expected there are extra characters getting added in the rendered text (please refer the image)[the output with extra characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXi9Q.png),
How do i fix this and make it look normal like [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvlOA.png)

i have tried removing the pattern and it works.
tried with both versions of swagger 3 and 2 getting same error.
but i want the pattern to be there